# Deprecation warning for capybara-webkit requiring Qt version 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt, rspec, capybara-webkit

When I run rspec, I get the following message:

`The next major version of capybara-webkit will require at least version 5.0 of Qt. You're using version 4.8.6.`

I was not aware I was using Qt, so know nothing of the implications of upgrading it.

How do I upgrade it and what precautions should I take before doing so?

Comment: The library you are using might be using Qt. I don't think installing Qt can help. Try to replace existing 4.8.6 libraries with 5.0 ones.

Comment: How do you do replace existing 4.8.6 libraries with 5.0 ones?

Comment: There is quite a bit of information about installing qt at https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit but could not see anything on how to do upgrade.

Comment: I have ran into this same issue and found an answer that got qt5 install for me here on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075380/can-i-use-homebrews-qt5-with-capybara-webkit/28509231#28509231 if you follow IAmNaNs answer, it should get you in good shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

equaleffect's comment above led me to [ImNaN answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075380/can-i-use-homebrews-qt5-with-capybara-webkit/28509231#28509231), i.e.

```
Comment out the capybara and capybara-webkit gems from your gemfile. Then:

    bundle
    gem uninstall capybara-webkit
    gem uninstall capybara # if it complains about dependencies 'gem uninstall' them first
    brew remove qt
    brew remove qt5 # if you've been playing around

From a clean environment (restart your terminal):

    brew install qt5
    brew linkapps qt5
    brew link --force qt5

Uncomment capybara and capybara-webkit in the gemfile and then:

    bundle install
```

Comment: As I have an Ubuntu system with no brew installed, I used this alternative solution, that seems to work nicely: `sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x` (as per instructions on [thoughtbot/capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#debian--ubuntu)) followed by `gem pristine capybara-webkit`.