# Capybara-webkit cannot handle link with bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec, capybara-webkit

I have a link:

```
link_to %q(<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'/>).html_safe, feed_item, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?',toggle: 'tooltip'}, method: :delete, title: 'Delete', id: 'delete_post'
```

and the following feature spec code

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link 'delete_post'
end
```

and I get the following error

```
Capybara::Webkit::ClickFailed:
       Failed to find position for element /html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='page-content-wrapper']/div/div[@id='main']/div[@id='main_content']/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/h3/div/a[@id='delete_post']
```

If I replace the span with the glyphicon by some text e.g. 'Delete', the test works.
This appears to be related to an unresolved [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/494) on Github, and may be to do with CSS overlaying the clickable html element.  However, I cannot understand how this overlaying is happening in this case or how to correct it.

It is becoming a common practice to use icons for common tasks like 'Edit" or 'Delete', so it would be good to find a solution to this.

How do I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that people work around this by modifying the test to either click the element using javascript or change the opacity of the overlying item. Instead, I went for the following, which is relies more on rails capabilities. I wrote a `trash_icon` helper as follows:

```
  def trash_icon
    if Rails.env.test?
      'proxy_for_trash_icon'
    else
      "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'/>".html_safe
    end
  end
```

and modified my link to:

```
link_to trash_icon, feed_item, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?',toggle: 'tooltip'}, method: :delete, title: 'Delete', id: 'delete_post'
```

and the test to:

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link 'proxy_for_trash_icon'
end
```

This tests everything except the exact text/icon used in the production system.

Still, hopefully someone will come up with a solution that is not a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Although *Obromios* answer would work, I don't think it's a good idea to change the way you render icons. Specially because you would need to add the **if Rails.env.test?** to every icon rendering in order to make the test work.

What you can do is to use this:

```
find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash').trigger('click')
```

instead of this:

```
click_link 'delete_post'
```

Comment: I had to use `find('.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash').click` to work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ariel_scherman's answer, you will not want to forget to add `js: true` to the beginning of your test example.

Something like this:

```
feature "delete the glyphicon", js: true do
   ............
end
```

This enables your javascript drivers to be enabled

Answer (score -1):

Build your capybara-webkit with Qt 5.5.1 , there was an issue in < 5.3 or so where pseudo elements didn't provide any size to the link so there was nowhere to click it

Comment: Alas, I am using Q5 5.5.1_1 and just to be sure, I rebuilt Capybara and Webkit using http://stackoverflow.com/a/33643674/1299362, and this did not solve the problem.

Comment: I can vouch for the comment here, 551 does not solve this issue. (we hacked around and added a min-width: 1px; for icons in our test run via a page.evaluate_script injection on visit.