# Capybara unable to test delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to write a test and I am getting really stumped.
I am using a helper to render a link

```
module DeleteLinksHelper
  def link_to_destroy(object)
    opts = {
      method: :delete,
      remote: true,
      id: "#{object.class.name.downcase}-#{object.id}-delete" 
       ### have tried with and without giving it an id
    }

     link_to object, opts do
       content_tag(:span, nil , class: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove")
     end
  end
end
```

this all works fine when I run the server it deletes the object i hand it. the problems start when I try to write an integration test with capybara.

```
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  # Have tried many ways of selecting/clicking the link and span elements
  page.find('span.glyphicon-remove').click
  page.find("#component-#{c.id}-delete > span").click

Capybara::Webkit::ClickFailed: Failed to find position for element /html/body/div/div[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[@id='components-pane']/ul/li[@id='component497695656']/div/a[@id='component-497695656-delete']/span
```

I saved the page just before and it has the entire page of html as it should be.

```
<a id="component-497695656-delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/components/497695656">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```

However if i save a screenshot at the same time it only shows the footer.

[image: screenshot just before click]

Yeah!!! That's the whole screenshot! Whats going on here? Does it have to do with the webkit driver?

Comment: On potential issue is that the capybara-webkit driver replaces all custom fonts with Arial - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/43ebe80704e118ba690d62049fe346fbe787e050/src/WebPage.cpp#L117 - due to a bug in an older version of QtWebKit.  If the character code glyphicon uses for the remove icon doesn't exist in Arial then your span will have 0 width on the page and not be locatable.  The blank screenshot could happen if you're using CSS features unsupported by capybara-webkit (it's basically a 5 year old browser) or the page isn't yet fully loaded.

Comment: I am using the bootstrap glyphicons. since you mentioned that bug I have been reading [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/494) issue which seems to have a lot of workarounds and a possible answer pointing at the version of qt.

Comment: If you didn't originally build capybara-webkit with Qt5.5.1 definitely try that.  You should also look at issues https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/728 and https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/808

Comment: I ran `qmake --version` says using Qt version 5.5.1 should I rebuld capybara-webkit?

Comment: sure nothing to lose - no guarantee that it fixes it though due to the other issues

Comment: I made sure I was using qt 5.5.1 uninstalled and reinstalled capybara-webkit to no avail. I did get it to find the element using [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36620706/4017627) but the click never makes it to the controller.